# Kubernetes Service IP entry in IP tables

Tags: kubernetes

Deployed pod using replication controller with replicas set to 3. Cluster has 5 nodes. Created a service (type nodeport) for the pod. Now kube-proxy adds entry about the service into ip-tables of all 5 nodes. Would it not be a overhead if there are 50 nodes in the cluster?

Comment: I agree there will be little bit overhead. Adding the iptables rules on all nodes is by design; this gives the ability to schedule the pods on available node.  Also I read somewhere iptables utilize efficient algorithm to look-up the iptables rule and routes the traffic.

Comment: But what exactly is your question? How to not do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an overhead. Every node needs to be able to communicate with services even if it does not host the pods of that service (ie. it may have pods that connect to that service).

That said, in some very large clusters it was reported that performance of iptables updates might be poor (mind that this is for a very, very big scale). If that is the case, you might prefer to look into solutions like Linkerd (https://linkerd.io/) or Istio (https://istio.io/)